# Postfix - How to enable SMTP authentication on local delivery

Tags: postfix, domain, spam, telnet, local

I have an email server running Postfix. Everything is working fine,
However, recently, some internal emails received emails from their own addresses with phishing content.
After finding out, I learned that Postfix can send internal emails using telnet port 25, sending it internally in my domain does not require authentication.
I got the idea of enabling authentication with local domain emails, I searched but got no answer. I appreciate the help
Sorry my English is not good so I have to use google translate

Answer (score 2):

**It's alerting that someone from the localhost is able to send phishing mail: it means someone is already inside the system or there's e.g. a web application that enables those connections. You shouldn't accept this, but carefully investigate where it's coming from and stop it.**

That said, to answer your question, there's nothing special with local delivery regarding SMTP on port `25`. Removing this permission could be done (in the `main.cf`) simply by either

- removing the `permit_mynetworks` from `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` or
- removing the `127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128` from `mynetworks`.

However, with this your local users must use the *submission* port(s) to deliver their mail. The authenticated users can by default use any address as an envelope sender. To limit this, the `submission` and/or `smtps` services in `master.cf` should have:

```
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

Here, the `hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` is the same that is used for `virtual_alias_maps`, because it already has the required `address@example.com username` format with the correct address to user mappings.

Comment: Thank you for consulting the solution.
I just want to prevent using terminal or mail sender to spread spam and phishing mail in the local domain.
Lik e the image below. Anyone can do this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/kMWATmBrNR4bz8si7

Comment: This answer covers exactly that considering local users. However, there are other configuration problems that may leave your mail server an *open relay* where anyone from anywhere could send mail through it.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to open main.cf, search for all the instances of permit_mynetworks and comment them out, then issue a postfix reload.

Comment: Dear friend,
I followed the instructions you submitted but the issue is still not resolved.
I can still telnet port 25 and send email without authentication

Comment: Make sure you are not testing by sending email to one of the domains listed in the postfix transport map.